# Wordpress Multisite Memory Spike

Tags: php, wordpress, memory, multisite

I have quite a large Wordpress multisite installation. I suspect one of my websites on this installation is getting hit hard momentarily causing a memory spike to kill the server, requiring a of the VM. This has happened twice today, once in the morning and once this evening.

Is there a way with Wordpress to check and see what site might be causing this so I can narrow down the issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way with Wordpress to check and see what site might be
>   causing this so I can narrow down the issue?

You need to look in the logs of the VM to see what caused the crashes. That will be much more useful than WordPress logging.

And/or use a utility like http://mmonit.com/monit/ If your VM is managed with WHM or Cpanel, you may be able to install Monit via that interface.

Take a look at https://github.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl to check memory usage and configs for MySQL; incorrect configs can make a buge difference in performance.

And delete post/page revisions to reduce the database size: https://wordpress.org/plugins/thin-out-revisions/ and/or https://gist.github.com/mrazzari/9240993

Comment: Thanks for the answer @songdogtech. I'll have a look through the logs. I was wondering if there was something WP specific, but if not then I guess the logs is my best bet. Thanks!

Comment: I added more info regarding memory usage and MySQL; that may be the trouble.